# How to instantiate class in python dynamically?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm using method dispatcher in CherryPy. In the server/start.py part of the server, I need to instantiate the API classes.

To make it more modular, and not to put everything in the start.py file, I coded it like this.

So, I've a dict which has all the instantiated api classes.

```
services = {}
user = UserResource() #api class
foo = FooResource() #api class
services = {"user":user, "foo":foo}

class Server(object):
    """Initialise the Cherrypy app"""
    #for service in services:
    user = services.values()[0]


cherrypy.quickstart(Server())
```

That works. But, if I do `services.keys()[0] = services.values()[0]` it doesn't work at all. No routes.

How do I do such a thing? Where I don't have to assign it to a particular class inside the server class, but rather use the keys to add routes.

Comment: First of all, there is no guarantee of order for `keys()` and `values()`. Also, `service.keys()` returns a list of keys, and you are assigning to the first item in the list, not changing the original dictionary.

Comment: @bereal while that's true, the documentation is clear that if no intervening changes are made, iterating through keys and values is guaranteed to return them in the same order.

Comment: @DanielRoseman With `services = {"user":1, "foo":2}`, I get `services.values()[0]` equal to `2` but the OP expects `1`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman still, if the OP wants to get `user` from the dictionary, he should not rely on the order.

Comment: @MaximeLorant ah, I meant that keys and values match up, not that they will be returned in any particular order. You and bereal are probably right that the OP is expecting them to be ordered.

Comment: As of now, I don't really care about the order, rather than the route working. Currently, I'm not able to get something like user = UserResource() in the server class, by using a list of already instantiated class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`services.keys()` simply returns a list. Setting the first element of that list to anything will have no effect.

I expect you want to do `services[services.keys()[0]] = services.values()[0]`, although I can't imagine what you are trying to do with that code.

**Edit**

OK, I think I understand what you want to do. It seems that CherryPy relies on class-level attributes to define the routes it will serve. The [docs](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/progguide/REST.html#a-quick-example) show how to do this dynamically. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
class Server(object):
    pass

for k, v in services:
    setattr(Server, k, v)
```

Note that the setattr has to be done outside the class definition itself, as the Server name doesn't exist inside the class body.

Comment: Not really. I want something like this in Server class. user = UserResource(). Now how do I load the already instantiated classes stored in a dict or a list, into the Server class to that there will be routes for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more routing flexibility, use [RoutesDispatcher](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorial/dispatching.html?highlight=routes#other-dispatchers).

Comment: It will benefit the OP more if you will kindly explain and expand on your answer as to why you believe the link you've provided will point him to the right answer. :)